# Open excel from powershell not in read-only to allow manual editing

Tags: excel, windows, powershell

My script currently scrapes some web data and places it into an excel file. However, I need to manually edit some fields before the script continues on.

My question is, once Ive scraped the data into excel, how do I open the application (with my new workbook) and allow editing?

I’ve tried start-process excel.exe  but it opens with a read-only warning.

Thank you

Comment: where's the code at?

Answer (score 0):

Excel as an application always can do read and write. The question is if the file you are trying to open can be read-only. A read-write file can become read-only when emailed or downloaded. it is the file you want to check.